# How can I get all my Gmail contacts to show up in my Hangouts phone list?

Tags: google-contacts, google-hangouts

When I first installed Hangouts, the phone list was populated with what was then all of my Gmail contacts that had phone numbers assigned. Since then I've added a bunch of Gmail contacts but they don't show up in my Hangouts phone list.

Is there a way to update the list or somehow keep them synchronized all the time?